# Thuja growing under my house?

Tags: roots

I have a 6 meter high thuja at 1 meter from the walls of my house with no foundation under my house. Do I risk destabilising my house?

Comment: Hi Veerie, welcome. What do you mean by no foundation. Maybe a photo might help.